# How to fix spaCy en_model incompatible with current spaCy version (2.3.2)?

Tags: python-3.x, model, spacy, named-entity-recognition

When I am running my NER model I am getting:

```
UserWarning: [W031] Model 'en_model' (0.0.0) requires spaCy v2.2 and is incompatible with the current spaCy version (2.3.2)
```

Please advise how can I fix it?

Python 3.7.9, spaCy 2.3.2, Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: It's a warning, so you may run this model unless you run into error. At this point you have to either downgrade or download model for your version with `spacy download model_name`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved by downgrading spaCy to 2.2.4.

```
pip3 install spacy==2.2.4
```